# SQL ratio of value to max column value by group

Tags: mysql, sql

I thought this would be of general interest to the group because it is an actual job interview SQL question that I got wrong. I think I was close but can someone provide the correct answer?

```
Brand  |  Model  |  Price
Braun  |  KF7150 |  98
Braun  |  KF7000 |  70
Braun  |  KF400  |  55
Krups  |  KM730  |  67
Krups  |  KM4689 |  130
Krups  |  EC311  |  50
```

For the above table (Coffee), provide the code that displays brand, model, price, and the ratio of each model's price to the highest price of its brand, rounded to nearest 2 decimal places.

This code I know is wrong because it simply selects the overall max price (130).

```
SELECT Brand, Model, Price, ROUND(Price/(SELECT MAX(Price) FROM Coffee),2)
 as Price_to_Brand_Highest
FROM Coffee
ORDER BY Brand;
```

I tried a self join but all the ratios came back as 1 because each price was divided by itself.

```
SELECT C1.Brand, C1.Model, C1.Price, ROUND(C1.Price/(SELECT MAX(C2.Price) 
    FROM Coffee where C1.Brand=C2.Brand),2) as Price_to_Brand_Highest
FROM Coffee C1
JOIN Coffee C2 on C1.Model=C2.Model
GROUP BY C1.Model
ORDER BY C1.Brand;
```

Comment: remove `JOIN Coffee C2 on C1.Model=C2.Model` and `GROUP BY C1.Model` and alias the table in the sub-query as `C2` and multiply the numerator or denominator by 1.0 (in the correlated sub-query)  to avoid integer division.

Answer (score 4):

You didn't specify a DBMS, so this is ANSI standard SQL:

```
select brand, model, price, 
       round(price / max(price) over (partition by brand), 2) as price_ratio
from coffee
order by brand, model;
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/HFZZRP41164

Comment: Thank you for creating the example on rextester. Sorry, I thought I had tagged this as mysql instead of just sql but that's the DBMS I was using.

Answer (score 2):

Before window functions were added to standard SQL, one method would be to join on a subquery that calculates the max value.

```
SELECT 
C1.*, 
ROUND(C1.Price/C2.MaxBrandPrice, 2) as Price_to_Brand_Highest
FROM Coffee C1
JOIN (
   Select Brand, max(Price) as MaxBrandPrice
   From Coffee
   Group by Brand
) C2
on (C1.Brand = C2.Brand)
ORDER BY C1.Brand, C1.Model;
```

Comment: Thanks. I believe that this is the answer that they were looking for in mysql.

Comment: Figured it was something like that.  Well, you could have told the interviewer to switch to MariaDB (which has [window functions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/window-functions/)) and then the answer from @a_horse_with_no_name would be the cooler standard SQL solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
; with Max_v as (
    Select Brand, max(Price) as MaxBrandPrice
        From Coffee
        Group by Brand
)
select Coffee.*, Max_v.price/(Max_ps.MaxBrandPrice*1.0)
    from Coffee, Max_v
    where D.Disease_ID = Max_ps.Disease_ID
    order by D.Disease_ID, D.ps desc
```

Comment: FYI: This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. You may want to improve it .